# Broken encoding UTF-8 when use Encoding() and tokens()

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, quanteda

I've got quite strange problem with encoding. When I run `Encoding(txt) <- "UTF-8"`, I get encoding broken and strings look like "\xe7\xed\xe0\xfe\xf2".

```
txt <- c("привет", "пока")
Encoding(txt) # I get "unknown" "unknown"
Encoding(txt) <- "UTF-8"
Encoding(txt) # I get "UTF-8" "UTF-8", but strange symbols in vector
```

Plus, when I run l10n_info(), I get

```html
$MBCS
[1] FALSE

$`UTF-8`
[1] FALSE

$`Latin-1`
[1] FALSE
```

I know, that I can use `enc2utf8()` with strings, but I work with quanteda and get the same issue as here: https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda/issues/1387 (but reinsalling package from github didn't help). I think, that problrm is with encoding on server.

P.S. dataframe loaded from excel is displayed correctly + when I save tokens object into new xslx, all the strings displayed in cyrillic.

Here is my session info:

```html
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server 2012 R2 x64 (build 9600)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251  LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251    LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251 LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] tsne_0.1-3         stringi_1.5.3      tm_0.7-8           NLP_0.2-1          DataCombine_0.2.21 emo_0.0.0.9000     ggplot2_3.3.3      reshape2_1.4.4    
 [9] topicmodels_0.2-12 ldatuning_1.0.2    writexl_1.3.1      plyr_1.8.6         quanteda_2.9.9000  stringr_1.4.0      readxl_1.3.1
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Encoding issues are tricky, especially on Windows systems.  It looks like your native encoding system is Windows-1251, an 8-bit encoding for Cyrillic.  So when you input your string, it is input in that encoding.  You can convert it to Unicode, but it still won't necessarily display correctly if you use the print method.

Here's the result of me trying to simulate the problem on my macOS platform.

```
> stringi::stri_info()$Charset.native[1:2]
$Name.friendly
[1] "UTF-8"

$Name.ICU
[1] "UTF-8"
```

My guess is that your system will show something different, but I cannot be sure.\

```
> # on macOS 10.15.7
> txt <- c("привет", "пока")
> txt
[1] "\u043f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442" "\u043f\u043e\u043a\u0430"            
> Encoding(txt)
[1] "UTF-8" "UTF-8"
```

So that produces the same output that you are seeing, but it's encoded as UTF-8.  To simulate what that would look like if the system encoded it as Windows-1251, we can convert it:

```
> # convert to Windows-1251
> txt_1251 <- iconv(txt, from = "UTF-8", to = "WINDOWS-1251")
> print(txt_1251)
[1] "\xef\xf0\xe8\xe2\xe5\xf2" "\xef\xee\xea\xe0"        
> cat(txt_1251)
������ ����> Encoding(txt_1251)
[1] "unknown" "unknown"
```

Is that what you are seeing?

You can try fixing it this way:

```
> txt_from1251 <- stringi::stri_conv(txt_1251, from = "windows-1251", to = "utf-8")
> print(txt_from1251)
[1] "\u043f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442" "\u043f\u043e\u043a\u0430"            
> cat(txt_from1251)
привет пока> Encoding(txt_from1251)
[1] "UTF-8" "UTF-8"
```

So while it still does not print(), it shows correctly from cat(), and has the correct Encoding bit set.

I could be wrong about this since my understanding of Unicode and character sets in R is incomplete, and it seems to be quite platform and locale dependent.  I would happily see another response that improves this answer, or to hear your success or not with trying some of the fixes suggested above.

Comment: Yes, stri_conv works, I see normal strings with cat().

Comment: I saw "\xef\xf0\xe8\xe2\xe5\xf2" "\xef\xee\xea\xe0"  before convertation

Comment: But I have the same problem with tokens() after stri_conv(df$text, from = "windows-1251", to = "utf-8"). For example, tokens_select(selection="remove") still doesn't work, as well as tokens_replace(). But tokens_wordstem("ru") works. Plus, when I downloaded xlsx, I saw very strange symbols.

Comment: When I don't run stri_conv(df$text, from = "windows-1251", to = "utf-8"), I get error "stringi::stri_length(x) :
  invalid UTF-8 byte sequence detected; try calling stri_enc_toutf8()" when try tokens_select()

Comment: P.S. before tokenization and corpus formation, Encoding(df$text) gives "UTF-8". But when I create a vector from scratch, I get "unknown", as I have shown

Comment: Best is to convert your file to UTF-8 _before_ you read it into R. You can try to do this from Excel when you save as csv. You might be viewing it ok in Excel, but that's probably because your Excel is using Windows-1251. Once it's UTF-8, it should stay that way upon import.

Comment: This didn't work, it was all the same: strange symbols like "сѓ рµр сђр". I did some preprocessing steps using stringr, then I wrote csv, then read it (all without fileEncoding argument). Encoding(df$text) became "unknown" instead of "UTF-8". Next I used enc2utf8 with df$text, it worked! Almost all the functions of quanteda package worked, but I still see symbols like "\u044d\u0442" and tokens_replace with phrase argument doesn't work (toks <- tokens_replace(toks, pattern = phrase("образ жизн"), replacement = "образ_жизн").)

Comment: tokens_replace works with enc2utf8. toks <- tokens_replace(toks, pattern = phrase(enc2utf8("образ жизн")), replacement = enc2utf8("образ_жизн")). Thank you!

Comment: Glad you solved it. I was going to suggest a new question with a reproducible example, but if you've figured it out, great.